# CSS - changing box sizes and linking background images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Reorganising box layout/size of boxes

[image: html/css code]

Resize and reorganise boxes to fit around letters. I'm not sure how to insert an Imgur link which actually works, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I also want to move the boxes so that the letters fit within them - preferably in rows of three.

Comment: The link shows only black background

Comment: Please post your code as text and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Never post code as an image, we can't copy or edit it to test/fix ourself when it's an image.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).. Please also bear in mind that code should be copied and pasted in a code section or as a working snippet, not as an image..

Comment: sorry, the interface forced me to post it as an image for some reason.

Comment: i don't understand what exactly it is that you are asking. Please clarify your desired result.